# How can I return the name of a file ending by *ino using a shell script?

Tags: shell, scripting

I'm new at shell programming. I am using a shell script that compile and upload a `.ino` (here: `tb_20200930.ino`) file from a Raspberry Pi 4 to a Controllino MAXI Automation (Arduino based).

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "compile"
arduino-cli compile -v --fqbn CONTROLLINO_Boards:avr:controllino_maxi_automation ./tb_20200930.ino

echo "workaraound a bug in arduino-cli"
rm -rf ./tb_20200930.CONTROLLINO_Boards.avr.controllino_maxi_automation.hex
cp ./tb_20200930.ino.CONTROLLINO_Boards.avr.controllino_maxi_automation.hex ./tb_20200930.CONTROLLINO_Boards.avr.controllino_maxi_automation.hex

echo "liberate the serial port for upload"
sudo systemctl stop testbench.service

echo "upload to the arduino"
arduino-cli upload -v -p /dev/ttyACM0 --fqbn CONTROLLINO_Boards:avr:controllino_maxi_automation 

echo "start the program on the raspberry pi"
sudo systemctl start testbench.service
```

I want to improve this script so I don't have to change it anymore.
I would like that the script search `.ino` files and pass it as a parameter. If more than 1 `.ino` files, the script would ask which file it needs to compile. If no `.ino` files found, print an error message. I tried

```
INOFILE="*.ino"
#echo $INOFILE
stringarray=($INOFILE)
a=0
while [ ${stringarray[$a]} -ge 0 ] 
do                                                                                    

done  
echo ${stringarray[0]}
echo ${stringarray[1]}
```

How to check if `stringarray[$a]` is empty? What is the type of `INOFILE`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this one, just set the variable `<path_to_ino_files>`  :

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a stringarray
stringarray="$(ls -1 <path_to_ino_files> | grep .ino\$)"

if [ ${#stringarray[@]} -ne 0 ]; then

for inofile in "${stringarray[@]}"
do
   ino="$(realpath "$inofile")"
   arduino-cli compile -v --fqbn CONTROLLINO_Boards:avr:controllino_maxi_automation "$ino"
done
fi
```

`if [ ${#stringarray[@]} -eq 0 ];` Check if the array is empty
`stringarray[@]` : contains all elements of the array

`for inofile in "${stringarray[@]}"` : loop through the array and set the current array value into inofile variable

`realpath "$inofile" :` Get the absolute path of the *ino* file.

Comment: `stringarray` in your code is no array. It is a single string. Had you used `stringarray=( somepath/*.ino )`, then it would have been an array. However, it makes little sense to use a separate array here as you may just as well just loop over the pattern: `for inofile in somepath/*.ino; do ...; done`.

Comment: Yes thanks I didnt copied all the script :)

Comment: Thank you, I think I get it.

Comment: Could you mark it as resolved :)